# Help with Pivot / Unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table as below

```
Name    Priority    Date    
-------------------------
A         2          d1
B         3          d2
```

How to write a query to achieve the below output

```
ColumnNames   d1      d2
--------------------------
 Name         A       B
 Priority     2       3
```

Thanks

Comment: This looks familiar... is this from the same requirements as the question you asked the other day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I promised:

**EDIT**: I modified my answer to answer additional questions by the OP.

A few things to note:

- The STUFF function: This is used to convert the XML string into a regular string (and to remove the first comma)
- Group By (I stole this from OMG Ponies): You need to do this to ensure you don't have any duplicate dates
- Make sure there aren't too many dates in the table before you run this.  Too many columns can be a problem
- NVARCHAR: I used this instead of VARCHAR for the @sql variable because sp_ExecuteSQL requires it.
- CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateColumn, 101): I did this because unless you convert the date to a string, this wont work.  101 results in this: mm/dd/yyyy but you can use whatever you need (make sure the 2 times it is used in this script matches)
- In order for this to work for multiple columns, you must first use UNPIVOT and convert all columns to the same datatype (more information below the code)
- It is important to note that in order to concatenate strings, they must be of the same datatype, with the same size (in my case, they are both NVARCHAR(MAX))

Read [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for more information on converting dates to strings.

With that said, here is the code:

```
-- table with multiple columns
CREATE TABLE #TBL ( 
    NameColumn VARCHAR(10), 
    PriorityColumn INT,
    AnotherColumn FLOAT,
    DateColumn DATETIME 
)


-- Insert the test data
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES ('a', 1, 7.2, '1/1/2000')
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES ('a', 2, 8.9, '1/2/2000')
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES ('a', 2, 53.2, '1/3/2000')
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES ('a', 3, 9.12, '1/4/2000')
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES ('b', 2, 1.26, '1/1/2001')


DECLARE
    @sql NVARCHAR(max),
    @dates NVARCHAR(max)


-- I separated this to make the code easier to read
SET @dates = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT N',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateColumn, 101) + ']' AS [text()]
        FROM #TBL
        GROUP BY DateColumn
        ORDER BY DateColumn
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, N''
)


-- I will break this part of the code up below
SET @sql = N'SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ColumnName,
        ColumnValue,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateColumn, 101) AS DateString
    FROM (
        SELECT
            CAST(NameColumn AS VARCHAR(100)) AS NameColumn,
            CAST(PriorityColumn AS VARCHAR(100)) AS PriorityColumn,
            CAST(AnotherColumn AS VARCHAR(100)) AS AnotherColumn,
            DateColumn
        FROM #TBL
    ) P
    UNPIVOT (
        ColumnValue
        FOR ColumnName IN (NameColumn, PriorityColumn, AnotherColumn)
    ) UNPIV
) P2
PIVOT (
    MAX(ColumnValue)
    FOR DateString IN (' + @dates + N')
) PIV'

EXECUTE dbo.sp_ExecuteSQL @sql


DROP TABLE #TBL
```

Lets run through this a little

```
-- I first do an UNPIVOT on all of the columns I want to pivot on, at the same time, converting them to the same datatype
SELECT
    ColumnName,
    ColumnValue,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateColumn, 101) AS DateString
FROM (
    SELECT
        CAST(NameColumn AS VARCHAR(100)) AS NameColumn,
        CAST(PriorityColumn AS VARCHAR(100)) AS PriorityColumn,
        CAST(AnotherColumn AS VARCHAR(100)) AS AnotherColumn,
        DateColumn
    FROM #TBL
) P
UNPIVOT (
    ColumnValue
    FOR ColumnName IN (NameColumn, PriorityColumn, AnotherColumn)
) UNPIV
```

Once I do this, the data will look something like this:

```
ColumnName  ColumnValue DateString
----------------------------------
NameColumn      a       01/01/2000
PriorityColumn  1       01/01/2000
AnotherColumn   7.2     01/01/2000
NameColumn      a       01/02/2000
PriorityColumn  2       01/02/2000
AnotherColumn   8.9     01/02/2000
NameColumn      a       01/03/2000
PriorityColumn  2       01/03/2000
AnotherColumn   53.2     01/03/2000
NameColumn      a       01/04/2000
PriorityColumn  3       01/04/2000
AnotherColumn   9.12     01/04/2000
NameColumn      b       01/01/2001
PriorityColumn  2       01/01/2001
AnotherColumn   1.26     01/01/2001
```

Then we can use PIVOT like this to get all the columns we need:

```
PIVOT (
    MAX(ColumnValue)
    FOR DateString IN (' + @dates + N')
) PIV
```

Comment: Confused. I get the concept but unable to apply to my problem for desired output.

Comment: is the datatype of the dates column DATETIME?  If so, you'll need to write some dynamic SQL.  I can give you more details when I get home.  Right now, I don't have access to my code.

Comment: Alright. When I get home this evening, I will edit my answer with the dynamic sql (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: OK.  I modified my answer with the solution I promised.

Comment: @Gabriel: Thanks. That worked. I have edited my question and updated the output. Is it possible to display the column names as well in the output?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can just hard code that. I modified my answer again to reflect that.

Comment: thanks gabriel. i thought i could extend one column to various other columns. I really dont understand this complex query and am unable to figure out how to extend this query for 2 columns. I have edited my question by adding one more column in the mix. pls. help.

Comment: @Gabriel: Can you pls. modify the query for 2 columns? Pls. see the updated question.

Comment: I'm working on the solution.  I'll have it for you in a few minutes.

Comment: There you go.  This should answer all your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
create table NameAndDate (NameCol varchar(200), DateCol datetime);

insert into NameAndDate (NameCol, DateCol) values ('A', '2010-03-04');
insert into NameAndDate (NameCol, DateCol) values ('B', '2010-03-05');

select * from NameAndDate;

select * from NameAndDate
pivot (
max(NameCol) 
for DateCol 
in ([2010-03-04], [2010-03-05])) 
as PivotResults;
```

This gives me the following results:

```
   NameCol     DateCol
---------------------------------------
1  A           2010-03-04 00:00:00.0000
2  B           2010-03-05 00:00:00.0000


   2010-03-04  2010-03-05
-------------------------
1  A           B
```

Note this requires you to know the dates ahead of time, when you write the query (unless you use dynamic SQL as mentioned by Gabriel).

Edit:

I tried using OMG Ponies' approach, but had to modify it like this:

```
declare @Dates nvarchar(max)
set @Dates = 
    (select '['+ convert(varchar, NameAndDate.DateCol) + '],' 
    from NameAndDate
    group by NameAndDate.DateCol
    order by NameAndDate.DateCol
    for xml path(''))
set @Dates = left(@Dates, len(@Dates) - 1)

declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)
set @SQL = 
    'select *  
    from NameAndDate
    pivot (
    max(NameCol) 
    for DateCol in (' + @Dates + ')) 
    as PivotResults'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

This gives me these results:

```
   Mar 4 2010 12:00AM   Mar 5 2010 12:00AM
------------------------------------------
1  A                    B
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @dates NVARCHAR(max)

SET @dates = SELECT '['+ t.date +"],"
               FROM TABLE t
           GROUP BY t.date
           ORDER BY t.date
            FOR XML PATH('')

@SQL = 'SELECT * 
          FROM TABLE 
         PIVOT(MAX(name) FOR date IN (@dates)) AS pvt'

BEGIN 

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dates NVARCHAR(max)', @dates

END
```